# Activate conda environment within a new xterm terminal

Tags: bash, conda, xterm

If I run

```
xterm -hold
```

and within the new terminal I type

```
conda activate my_environment
```

the conda environment "my_environment" is indeed activated.

However, when passing this command using the -e flag, it does not work:

```
xterm -hold -e "conda activate my_environment"
```

It instead returns the following error message:

```
CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'.
To initialize your shell, run

    $ conda init <SHELL_NAME>

Currently supported shells are:
  - bash
  - fish
  - tcsh
  - xonsh
  - zsh
  - powershell

See 'conda init --help' for more information and options.

IMPORTANT: You may need to close and restart your shell after running 'conda init'.
```

So, how can this be done using xterm? Or should I use another type of external terminal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Background

The `conda activate` command is a shell function that gets defined during initialization of the shell. `conda init` adds code to the initialization file (e.g., `.bash_profile`) to run the scripts that define the `conda activate` shell function.

## Solutions

#### Possible fix: `xterm` options

When using the `-c` argument with `xterm` it no longer runs the initialization script. Hence, `conda activate` never gets defined. For `bash` there is the `-l` that tells it to run the init files. I expected xterm's `-ls` argument to trigger similar behavior, but it didn't work for me. Perhaps someone more familiar can point you to the correct flag.

#### Manually Run Conda Script

Otherwise, you just run the Conda script yourself (assuming it's the bash version). Either of these will work:

```
xterm -hold -e ". /path/to/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh && conda activate my_environment && which python"
```

or

```
xterm -hold -e "$(conda shell.bash hook) && conda activate my_environment && which python"
```

The `which python` is only included to show that you're getting the env activated.

#### Conda Run

Another option is `conda run`, which automates executing commands under an environment. The follow is equivalent to what I did in the last section, but without having to know what shell I am running in:

```
xterm -hold -e "conda run -n my_environment which python"
```

Just be aware that this functionality is still a work-in-progress. Personally, I've found it quite useful for running simple scripts in specific envs and haven't run into problems.

Comment: Thanks, the last option already worked, did not check the previous ones though.

Comment: Spent the good part of a day figuring out how to get it to work. Thanks a lot for the last suggestion using `conda run`, it worked flawlessly.